# Return Type Boolean in Java

Tags: java, types, return-type

I have a question on `boolean` return types.
Check the following code:

## Code Sample 1

```
boolean flag = sampleMethod();

public boolean samplemethod(){
    return false;
}
```

## Code Sample 2

```
sampleMethod();

public boolean samplemethod(){
    return false; 
}
```

In the above two examples, the code compiles properly without any compile time or run time exceptions.
My doubt is, Java doesn't make it mandatory for the `boolean` return type to be assigned in the calling program, where for the other data types the program does not work.
Can you please explain the reason for this to me?

Comment: first, the above code does _not_ compile. And second, this behaviour is the same for all types.

Comment: Please use the 'code' tag to enhance readability. And maybe you should compile the code before posting it ... as Java is case sensitve it will not compile.

Comment: Please alywas post working code, not “something like this” code.

Comment: This is the same for all return types. An example: removing an item from a List in Java returns the removed object. This is optional information though, and in many cases you won't need the object after you removed it from that list, so a language forcing you to assign that return value would make programming tedious. Similarly, many processes return a boolean success status that doesn't necessarily need to be checked afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @DR says, Java does not force you to assign the result of a method call.  A void or non-void method call is valid as a complete statement in Java.

I would surmise that the reasons Java is designed this way include the following:

- Convenience: most developers would find it a nuisance if the result of every non-void method call had to be assigned.
- Tradition: C, C++ and almost no other language force you to do this. (I have vague recollections of some language that did ... but that was long ago.)
- Futility: you cannot stop the developer from assigning the result to a temporary variable and then ignoring it.  Or writing a wrapper method that does the same thing.
- Better alternatives: if you want to encourage the developer to pay attention to an error in Java, throw an appropriate checked exception.

Answer (score 11):

Java **never** forces you to assign the return value of a function call. There must be something wrong with your *other* code (you might post it here, too)

PS: This reminds me of good old Turbo Pascal, where you had to enable the Extended Syntax to get this behaviour.

Comment: I am not focusing on whether it compiles or not, main question is the calling program doesnot make it mandatory to assign the return boolean value from the method.

Comment: the answer was pretty clear that Java never forces you to assign the return value.

Answer (score 0):

`javac` cannot issue a warning when you forget to assign the result to a variable, but [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) can.

```
@CheckReturnValue(explanation="...")
public boolean samplemethod(){
    return false; 
}

sampleMethod(); // Now generates a warning
```

Comment: This still doesn't compile unless `sampleMethod();` is called from inside an actual function though. Otherwise it's seen as illegal function _definition_ without a return type set.

Comment: @Nyerguds, of course. I assume it is obvious from context that the call to `sampleMethod();` is within another method somewhere.  The same applies to the code sample in the question.